# Show related products, exclude current product from grid

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a grid that shows related products in Cakephp2, it works just fine however the same product being viewed shows up in the grid of related products, how can i exclude it?

Here is my artworks controller code:

```
    public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$this->Artwork->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid artwork'));
    }
    $options = array('conditions' => array(
        'Artwork.' . $this->Artwork->primaryKey => $id),
        'recursive' => 0);
    $artwork = $this->Artwork->find('first', $options);
    $this->set('artwork', $artwork);

    // related artworks
    $status = 'Artwork.status';
    $id = 'Artwork.artist_id';
    $related = $this->Artwork->find('all',
        array(
           'limit' => 4, 
           'conditions' => array(
             $status => 1, 
             $id => $artwork['Artwork']['artist_id'])));

    $this->set('artworks', $related);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude the Artwork from related:

```
'Artwork.id !=' => $artwork['Artwork']['id']
```

Try this:

```
public function view($id = null) {
if (!$this->Artwork->exists($id)) {
    throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid artwork'));
}
$options = array('conditions' => array(
    'Artwork.' . $this->Artwork->primaryKey => $id),
    'recursive' => 0);
$artwork = $this->Artwork->find('first', $options);
$this->set('artwork', $artwork);

// related artworks
$status = 'Artwork.status';
$id = 'Artwork.artist_id';
$related = $this->Artwork->find('all',
    array(
       'limit' => 4, 
       'conditions' => array(
         $status => 1, 
         $id => $artwork['Artwork']['artist_id'],
         'Artwork.id !=' => $artwork['Artwork']['id']
)));


$this->set('artworks', $related);
}
```